# Is there a way to display data from properties file to HTML file?

Tags: java, html, properties, thymeleaf

Is there a way to display data from properties file to HTML with *thymeleaf*? Say I have *global_en.properties*:

```
userId = Username EN
```

And I have in my HTML something like:

```
<label> <span th:text="#{userId}"></span> </label>
```

Here, it displays Username EN properly. However, how would I do it if I have another *global_jp.properties* with:

```
userId = Username JP
```

It has the same key value with *global_en.properties*. Basically, what I want to do is display Username EN when the user selects English and Username JP when the user selects Japanese as language.

Edit:
Ok, so I have this in my servlet.xml:
The locale interceptor is declared under mvc:interceptors

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
      <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
      <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="false" />
      <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
      <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
    </bean>
<mvc:interceptor>
  <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
  <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/css/**" />
  <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/img/**" />
  <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/js/**" />
  <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/lib/**" />
  <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/" />
  <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/index.do" />
  <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/C0001.do" />
  <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/pages/C0001.do" />
  <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/C0001Login.do" />
  <bean class="jp.co.vmt.qt.common.interceptor.LoginIntercept" />
</mvc:interceptor>
```

The local resolver

```
<!-- Internationalization -->
 <bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_UK" />
  </bean>
```

The location of the properties files

```
<!-- messages.properties location -->
  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
      <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/conf/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/conf/global</value>
            </list>
      </property>
  </bean>
```

To my understanding, those things are everything I need to get localization working, correct? I added in my URL "../action?lang=jp" but it's still displaying English versions. I'm not sure now where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle this in the backend of your application. It is explained here:
 http://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/13/part-4-internationalization-in-spring-boot/

Additionally, try to use Spring's standard naming i.e. `messages_en.properties` and `messages_jp.properties`